# RSpec FactoryBot.lint fails on a sequenced factory name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

Versions:

- Rails 5.2.0.beta2
- ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x86_64-darwin17]
- rSpec 3.7.0

Database cleaner and FactoryBot.lint running together in `support/factory_bot.rb`:

```
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.include FactoryBot::Syntax::Methods

  config.before(:suite) do
    DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    DatabaseCleaner.clean_with :truncation

    begin
      DatabaseCleaner.start
      FactoryBot.lint strategy: :build unless config.files_to_run.one?
    ensure
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end
  end
end
```

Running `bin/rspec` returns this error:

```
jathayde$ bin/rspec

An error occurred in a `before(:suite)` hook.
Failure/Error: FactoryBot.lint strategy: :build unless config.files_to_run.one?

FactoryBot::InvalidFactoryError:
  The following factories are invalid:

  * project - Validation failed: Name has already been taken (ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid)
# ./spec/support/factory_bot.rb:10:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'


Finished in 0.60158 seconds (files took 2.66 seconds to load)
0 examples, 0 failures, 1 error occurred outside of examples
```

Here's the Project factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :project do
    sequence(:name) { |n| "Project-#{n}"}
    short_name { name.downcase.gsub(/[\s&\/]+/, "-") }
    association :category
    association :client
    page_title { name }
    meta_description "my text description"
  end
end
```

And here's the `models/project.rb` file:

```
class Project < ApplicationRecord
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :slug, use: [:slugged, :finders]

  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :category

  validates :name,            presence: true
  validates :short_name,      presence: true,
                              uniqueness: true
  validates :category,        presence: true
  validates :client,          presence: {
                                on: :create,
                                message: "Must have a client for a project" }
  validates :page_title,      presence: true

  before_validation :set_slug

  private

  def set_slug
    self.slug = "#{name}".parameterize
  end
end
```

Other notes:

- This occurs regardless of if the `uniqueness: true` is on the
  `short_name` in the model file.
- There are no unique constraints in the database schema.
- This also happens if I use `{Faker::Name.name}` for the project name (without a sequence)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this was the `category` association, and not the `project` itself that was the problem. The Category factory:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :category do
    name "Name"
    short_name { Faker::Lorem.word }
    description { Faker::Lorem.paragraph }
  end
end
```

changing to this resolved it:

```
FactoryBot.define do
  factory :category do
    name { Faker::Name.name }
    short_name { Faker::Lorem.word }
    description { Faker::Lorem.paragraph }
  end
end
```